# Creating time in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create time based execution of code. i.e. If current system time is between 9:21 am to 9:33 am, the code should execute.

But what I have written throws error:

```
from datetime import datetime

# get system time
Time = datetime.now().strftime ("%H:%M")

startTime = datetime.time(9,21)
midTime = datetime.time(9,33)

if Time < midTime and Time > startTime:
  # Run code
```

It throws error right when I try to create 9:21 am time.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

Comment: Don't use something like Time as a variable name.

Comment: Use `import datetime` then `datetime.time(9,21)`. 
Also, the if statement is comparing a `str` object (`Time`) to a `datetime` object.  Update the statement to compare *two* `datetime` objects.

Comment: You are effectively trying to call `datetime.datetime.time` where apparently you wanted `datetime.time`. The class hierarchy in the `datetime` module is rather strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @S3DEV's comment, you need to decide if you want to compare just the time or the full datetime. This approach follows what you were originally doing - is the current time between a given set of times. If the date matters, and it might, you would need to change your `datetime.time(...)` argument to something that also includes the date.

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
start_time = datetime.time(12, 21)
mid_time = datetime.time(13, 33)

if current_time < mid_time and current_time > start_time:
    print('hello')
else:
    print('goodbye')
```

Comment: You can also simplify the comparison to `if start_time < current_time < mid_time:`.